# Vuejs constants from backend API

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have an API at my backend

```
api/v1/constants
```

that returns all the application constants when requested. I want to call this API when my Vuejs application gets loaded and set these constants somewhere so that each vuejs component can import these constants and use them.

I can call this API in my root component and pass constants as a prop wherever needed. But it is making a chain of passing a prop to nested components.

For example

> component A passes constants to component B,
>
> component B passes constants to component C,
>
> and so on....

Please recommend if somebody has a better way to manage this.

Comment: I'd look at [vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex)

Comment: thanks for quick reply. How would I make sure that the constants get loaded  before any other component renders on the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Vue.prototype.$constants = <your constants>
```

Can be used anywhere in a Vue or component as

```
this.$constants.<some constant>
```

Comment: Seems good. @Bert how can I make sure that constants gets added in Vue prototype before any other component renders.

Comment: @Munish Don't initialize the Vue until the constants are retrieved. As in initialize the Vue in a promise callback.

Comment: I did the following and it is good

`Vue.http.get('/getConstants').then(res => {

    Vue.prototype.$constants = res.body.data;

    new Vue({

        el: '#app'

    });

});`